Adding initialize to body tag if I am using a specific ACF block
I am making a ACF block that includes a google map and I need to add:
onload="initialize()"
to the body tag.
Can I use PHP to add that code conditionally if a unique ACF block is being used on the page?
I tried this:
function check_if_block_exist($block_handle) {
  $post = get_post(); 

  if(has_blocks($post->post_content)) {
    $blocks = parse_blocks($post->post_content);

    foreach( $blocks as $block ) {
      if($block['blockName'] === $block_handle) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}

But it didn't work.

How you are passing the $block_handle in check_if_block_exist function?

"and I need to add: onload="initialize()" to the body tag" - no, you most likely don't need to do exactly that. Might probably make much more sense if you used wp_add_inline_script to add a proper DOMContentLoaded or jQuery ready handler.

C3roe, you are correct. I was able to remove initialize from the body tag and added it to my js. Thanks for your answer.
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

